# JPA and generics

Tags: java, generics, jpa

I'm wondering how an abstract class with generics would handle with JPA? I mean what kind of annotations do I need for the field?

Consider these:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AbstractMyClass<T> {
  // What about Strings and Integers? Do I need some kind of @LOB?
  private T field;

  public T getField() {
    return field;
  }

  public void setField(T field) {
    this.field = field;
  }
}
```

And then these

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "String")
public class MyStringClass extends AbstractMyClass<String> {
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "Integer")
public class MyIntegerClass extends AbstractMyClass<Integer> {
}
```

Comment: What implementation do you use?

Comment: Hibernate 3.6 with Oracle 10g as database. Also, I generate the tables manually by hand.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve on a design level? What's the point of having such a superclass?

Comment: Well, nothing major. Just got interested as I thought about the future.. I'm a total newbie when it comes to ORMs and I was wondering if they can and how they do solve this kind of problem.

Comment: Well, I tried with a String and Integer. It works fine as long as you can store the String in a varchar2, but I found easy no way to annotate this specific string as lob without custom types.

Answer (score 9):

JPA is perfectly able to handle your proposed, because the generic appears at the abstract class level and for your concrete classes it has exactly a single value per class. In fact, JPA will store your subclasses in one or more table, according to the @InheritanceStrategy you have chosen and uses different mechanism for that.

You can figure out yourself why your case is not a problem, reasoning about how an ORM could save the two classes on a DB:

- You can store MyStringClass and MyIntegerClass in the same table, adding a Discriminator column so that the ORM, when it loads from the DB, know which constructor should be called.
- You can store every subclass in more table.

What is not possible, on the other side, is to define a generic

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MyGenericClass")
public class MyGenericClass<T> {
    private T t;
    public MyGenericClass(T t) {
       this.t=t;
    }
}
```

The reason for this is that, at compile time, the T is "erased" because of type erasure. It is used at compile time to verify signatures and correctness of types, but then it is turned into a java.lang.Object inside the JVM.  If you follow until now, you should be able to understand the following:

- In your case,  every concrete subclass of AbstractMyClass has a type T which is defined for all instances of the class. While the T information is not retained into the AbstractMyClass, it is retained and unique inside the subclasses.
- In the second case I posted, each possible concrete instance of MyGenericClass could have a possible different value for T, and because of type erasure this information is not retained.

*Note: the fact that the second case cannot be handled by JPA is absolutely reasonable and if you fall in that case you should ask yourself questions about your design. Generics are a great tool to design flexible classes which can handle other classes in a type-safe manner, but type-safe is a programming language concept which has nothing to do with persistance.

---

Extra  : you could use javap to see what really is erasure. Take off annotations from MyGenericClass and compile it.

```
G:\>javac MyGenericClass.java

G:\>javap -p MyGenericClass
Compiled from "MyGenericClass.java"
public class MyGenericClass extends java.lang.Object{
    private java.lang.Object t;
    public MyGenericClass(java.lang.Object);
}
```

Comment: I tried this and it produced a exception

    @Entity
    @Table(name = "MyFoo")
    public class MyFooClass extends AbstractMyClass<Foo> {
    }

    Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: fukoka.foobar.Foo, at table: MyFoo, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(field)]

Answer (score -2):

We can. if the `T` implements `Serializable`

```
@Entity
public class IgsSubject extends BasicObject implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5387429446192609471L;

@MappedSuperclass
public class IgsBasicLog<T> extends BasicObject {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ITEM_ID")
    private T item;

@Entity
public class IgsLogA extends IgsBasicLog<IgsSubject> implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8207430344929724212L;
}
```

Comment: Please explain why `T` needs to implement `Seralizable` since imo it needs to extend an entity type.