# EclipseLink + JPA + Generic Entity + SINGLE_TABLE Inheritance

Tags: java, generics, jpa, eclipselink, single-table-inheritance

I was wondering if it's possible in JPA to define a generic entity like in my case PropertyBase and derive concrete entity classes like ShortProperty and StringProperty and use them with the SINGLE_TABLE inheritance mode?

If I try to commit newly created ElementModel instances (see ElementModelTest) over the EntityManager I always get an NumberFormatException that "value" can't be properly converted to a Short. Strangely enough if I define all classes below as inner static classes of my test case class "ElementModelTest" this seems to work.

Any ideas what I need to change to make this work?

I'm using EclipseLink eclipselink-2.6.0.v20131019-ef98e5d.

```
public abstract class PersistableObject implements Serializable {

    private String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    private Long version;

}
```

```
public abstract class PropertyBase<T> extends PersistableObject {

    private String name;
    private T value;

}
```

```
public class ShortProperty extends PropertyBase<Short> {
    ...
}
```

```
public class StringProperty extends PropertyBase<String> {
    ...
}
```

```
public class ElementModel extends PersistableObject {

    private StringProperty name = new StringProperty();
    private ShortProperty number = new ShortProperty();

}
```

```
public class ElementModelTest extends ModelTest<ElementModel> {

    @Test
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void testSQLPersistence() {

        final String PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME = getClass().getPackage().getName();
        new File("res/db/test/" + PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME + ".sqlite").delete();

        EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME);
        EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();

        em.getTransaction().begin();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
            ElementModel device = new ElementModel();
            device.setName("ElementModel: " + i);
            device.setNumber((short) i);
            em.persist(device);
        }

        em.getTransaction().commit();
        em.close();

    }

}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<entity-mappings version="2.1"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/orm" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/orm http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/orm_2_1.xsd">

    <mapped-superclass
        class="PersistableObject">
        <attributes>
            <id name="id">
                <column name="id" />
            </id>
            <version name="version" access="PROPERTY">
                <column name="version" />
            </version>
        </attributes>
    </mapped-superclass>

    <entity class="PropertyBase">
        <table name="PropertyBase" />
        <inheritance />
        <discriminator-column name="type"/>
        <attributes>
            <basic name="name">
                <column name="name" />
            </basic>
            <basic name="value">
                <column name="value" />
            </basic>
        </attributes>
    </entity>

    <entity class="StringProperty">
        <discriminator-value>StringProperty</discriminator-value>
    </entity>

    <entity class="ShortProperty">
        <discriminator-value>ShortProperty</discriminator-value>
    </entity>

    <entity class="ElementModel">
        <table name="ElementModel" />
        <inheritance />
        <discriminator-column name="type"/>
        <attributes>
            <one-to-one name="name">
                <join-column name="name" referenced-column-name="id" />
                <cascade>
                    <cascade-all />
                </cascade>
            </one-to-one>
            <one-to-one name="number">
                <join-column name="number" referenced-column-name="id" />
                <cascade>
                    <cascade-all />
                </cascade>
            </one-to-one>
        </attributes>
    </entity>

</entity-mappings>
```

Comment: TL;DR - can you reduce the amount of work others have to put in to comprehend your issue? reduce the code to the relevant details - no ctors, no accesor methods, only essential attributes, give each file a separate listing? And welcome to StackOverflow :)

Comment: Thanks for your hints and sorry for the clutter ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that `PropertyBase<T>` is an entity with field `value` being persistable. Your database needs to map that field type to a column type, and you have three entities that have different java types for the same field: `PropertyBase<T>` is generic and has itself no idea what type its `value` field is, `StringProperty` says it is a String and `ShortProperty` says that is a Short. So that is a conflict.

In order to overcome this problem, you make field `value` transient, and for every subtype of `PropertyBase<T>` (like `StringProperty`) you can define a new persitable property with different names, eg.
`StringProperty` will have a `private String stringValue`, `ShortProperty` will have a `private Short shortValue`, and every field will be mapped to different DB column.

PS: I cannot explain why it works when you make all the classes `static inner`.

Comment: Related to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11260856/jpa-and-generics) it should work in principle. The difference between the "normal" and the "inner static" approach is the type of the value column, which is in the first case NUMBER and in the second case VARCHAR.

Comment: In that related question, your `PropertyBase<T>` would be a `@MappedSuperclass` and not an `@Entity` with JPA inheritance there, so that is something different, as there is no conflict. Note in that single answer, that the case, that does not work, is exactly your case. Also have you tried the scheme I described above?

Comment: You are right, this is a different case and would lead to two different entity tables and my aim was it to have everything in one table (single table inheritance). Inspired by your scheme I've tried something different and removed the `value` field from `PropertyBase<T>` and marked the related getter and setter methods as `abstract`. In both derived classes `ShortProperty`and `StringProperty` I've defined the `value` field again and voila this seems to work now like the inner static approach. BTW: I think your scheme should work. I did something similar with list classes.

Comment: Update: My approach didn't work. I had problems persisting float values back and forth, because of the underlying constant database field type. So, I followed the originally suggested scheme, but removed the `value` field from the `PropertyBase<T>` class.